# What I am doing wrong with this pymongo aggregate query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
ff = db.collection.aggregate(
[
 { '$match': { "id_str":"1055193743425499137"} },
 { '$group': { "_id": "text", "No_of_Times": { '$sum': 1 } } }
]
 )
print(list(ff))
```

---

This is a sample of the document in my collection.

```
{"_id":"5bd0d561f94f845d9cb70f39",
 "id":"1055193743425499137",
 "id_str":"1055193743425499137",
 "text":"RT @WeNeedEU: This,....."}
```

I am trying to use an aggregate query to find the number of documents that match the id_str. The code above shows an empty list which I do not understand. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: you just need to use $ symbol before text.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not familiar with python
>
> Below query tested on `Mongo` GUI.

```
aggregate(
[
 { '$match': { "id_str":"1055193743425499137"} },
 { '$group': { "_id": "$text", "No_of_Times": { '$sum': 1 } } } //change "text" with "$text"
]
 )
```

OutPut:

```
{
    "_id" : "RT @WeNeedEU: This,.....",
    "No_of_Times" : 1.0
}
```